# How to force QGLWidget to update screen?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I’m drawing a simple scene with Open GL. I’ve subclassed QGLWidget and overriden paintGL(). Nothing fancy there:

```
void CGLWidget::paintGL()
 {
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    gluLookAt (120.0, 160.0, -300.0, 0.0 + 120.0, 0.0 + 160.0, 2.0 - 300.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glScalef(1.0f/300.0f, 1.0f/300.0f, 1.0f/300.0f);
    glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(80.0, width()/(double)height(), 5.0, 100000.0);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    glColor3f(1.0f,0.6f,0.0f);
    glVertex3d(x, y, z);

    // ...drawing some more points...

    glEnd();

 }
```

I have a timer in main window which triggers `updateGL()` of GL widget. I’ve verified that it results in `paintGL()` being called. However, the actual picture on the screen is only updated very rarely. Even if I resize the window, scene is not updated. Why is that and how can I force it to update?

Comment: May I ask: Why do you initialize the projection and MV matrix twice in `paintGL`? Do you draw something in between? If not, you overwrite the first matrices with the second ones and you can move this code into `resizeGL` (projection) and `initializeGL` (model-view)

Comment: @leemes: No idea, actually... It's a bug, remnants of my trying to find projection and MV parameters that actually work. Fixed, thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Don't call updateGL() from your timer, call update() instead to ensure that the view gets a paint event.

Comment: It doesn't work, `paintGL()` is not called at all then. Tried calling both, too - also doesn't work. But thanks for the hint.

Comment: Try sticking a breakpoint in QGLWidget::paintEvent and see if it gets there after calling update() and what happens after that.

Comment: It's only called when I resize the window.

Comment: Have you set any window flags in the constructor of your view?  update SHOULD cause you to get a paint event at some point in the near future  after calling it, providing you are letting the event loop run correctly and you have not disabled updates on the widget.  Not getting a paint event is your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot, found the problem! Was actually just a logical problem on my part, but your answers helped :)

Comment: What was the problem actually? I am having a similar problem and I couldn't figure it out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

inside your CGLWidget constructor

```
QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(update()));
timer->start(10);

timer -> start(VALUE);
```

play with `VALUE 10 is just an example.

Adorn

Comment: Hey, I have used this technique it works. Is there somehow I can immediately update the scene as soon as the previous scene is rendered because right now I have a bottleneck of 10ms from the timer. I can't go faster than that.

Comment: play with `VALUE 10 is just an example. if u put 1 there, it would be 1ms, point is not however, when you want to refresh the screen, point is when your scene is ready..

Comment: Exactly what I said. As soon as my scene is ready, I want update to be triggered.

Comment: then make sure if you really need a timer. also `timer(0)` will shoot out the timer immediately

Comment: Well, this is what I need to know, how do I remove the timer from the application itself. I would prefer not using it.